# Systemd-networkd and IPv6Token in 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, ipv6, systemd-networkd

I've been recently playing with IPv6 but I have a vexing problem with my
little Ubuntu box. Systemd-networkd (from systemd 245.4) is supposed to
understand a directive  like this:

IPv6Token=prefixstable:my_prefix

where my_prefix is exactly what my router sends in its RA, 64 bits,
ending in a double colon (::), verified by tcpdump. And what I wish to
get out of this is an IPv6 address generated as described in RFC7217,
i.e. a stable address where the lower 64 bits are not based on my MAC
address.

Unfortunately systemd-networkd does not seem to agree. It accepts the
directive without comment but I still get the EUI-64 address. Even if I
set log level to debug there's nothing in the log about this. I've tried
other forms in my_prefix but then networkd eagerly tells me it's wrong
but not what would be correct and actually **work**.

I can work around this in a bunch of ways so not looking for that,
but getting this to work would be easiest.

I looked but I haven't found any bug reports about this so I have a
feeling it should work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was netplan interfering with my attempts to change the network configuration. So, credit to Marko Moock on Usenet, I did as he suggested:

1. Disable netplan with this config in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:

   ```
   network:
     version: 2
     renderer: networkd
   ```
2. Setup my .network file in /etc/systemd/network:

   ```
    [Match]
    Name=eth0

    [Network]
    IPv6Token=prefixstable:myprefix::
    DHCP=ipv4
   ```
3. Run netplan try for a test, worked great.
4. Reboot and it still worked.